# Capture the previous value of change( ) in order to revert the input field to that value?

Tags: jquery

The use case is a web app form for doing some calculations...what else is new...

Normally, if a user enters a value that creates a NaN condition, I override the value to 0 to avoid the NaN. This works fine, it keeps everything working and prevents the NaN from propagating.

But functionally this is not ideal. The ideal thing to do would be simply to cancel the change() event and restore the previous value. Interrupting the event is no big deal, but is there way to do it so that the prior input value is restored/maintained without resorting to data/binding,etc.?

My reasoning is this: 'change()' must be aware of the previous value of the input, since change() is doing a before & after comparison of values to determine a change has occurred. So is it possible to capture this previous value from change()? That would be the question.

Comment: And from a UX perspective you should also inform the user that a character was used instead a number. A regex that would trim blanks and chars could that come really handy

Answer (score 2):

```
var prevVal;
var input = $("input_selector");
input.focus(function(){
  prevVal = input.val();
}).change(function(){
  if (isNaN(input.val())) {
    input.val(prevVal);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a variable to store the previous value and change it out according to the value, something like:

```
var input = $("input#text_input");
var prev_val = null;
input.on("change", function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(isNaN(val)) {
        input.val(prev_val);
        return(false);
    } else {
        prev_val = val;
        // Other stuff
    }
});
```